# Convert List<Model> to ObservableCollection<ViewModel>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am considerably new to MVVM implementation. This might sound like a repetitive question but there is nothing that I could find that would help me understand better with my knowledge which is basic. I have a `Model` class with members as shown here:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I have wrapped this model class in a view model but with `ObservableCollection` in place of `List`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Model model;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
    }
    //getters and setters for both Name and Age

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Children
    {
        //how to convert List<Model> to ObservableCollection<ViewModel> here?
    }
}
```

I definitely do not want to expose my `Model` class to the view which is why I need to create an `ObservableCollection` of the VM class. Not sure how to achieve this though. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want to return the `model`'s `Children` as an ObservableCollection of another type? Other than the conversion between `Model` and `ViewModel`, the constructor for [ObservableCollections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.110).aspx) can take a List as parameter, e.g. `return new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(*model.Children as List<ViewModel>*);`. Note that you need to do conversion of Model to ViewModel first.

Comment: **If I'm not mistaken, you want to return the model's Children as an ObservableCollection of another type?** Yes.That's exactly what I am looking to achieve. `ObservableCollections` does take a List as a parameter but the List should be of the same type. In my case they aren't..

Comment: Well, then there would be no other way than to create a function to convert. For example, in your `Model` class, you can have a `public ViewModel converted { get { *perform some conversion here* } }`, and then to convert the whole list you can simply do `return new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(model.Children.Select(m => m.converted));`

Comment: You wrote you "definitely do not want to expose my Model class to the view". Now you have a bunch of view model code to achieve this goal, but still have the problem that changes to the Model's Children collection won't be notified about. I'd suggest to use a far more pragmatic approach and 1.) implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the Model, 2.) use `ObservableCollection<Model>` for the Children property and 3.) derive ViewModel from Model. Neither ObservableCollection nor  INotifyPropertyChanged are view-specific, and may well be used in model classes.

Comment: Creating an `ObservableCollection<Model>` and deriving the ViewModel would still make me expose the Model objects through the Collection.

Comment: Sure, but it would significantly reduce the amount of code you write. And it would work out of the box with a view.

Comment: True.. But I have some Commands in my ViewModel and binding them to the controls whose parents are bound to the Model would be a bit of a hassle.

Comment: That would be no problem at all if you derive ViewModel from Model. Add the commands in the derived class.

Comment: Hmmm yeah that makes sense too..

Comment: *I am considerably new to MVVM implementation* hey, welcome aboard, it's a great way to develop WPF applications. Been doing it myself since WPF originally came out!  *I definitely do not want to expose my Model class to the view* yeesh. Do yourself a favor and forget about that. There's no reason to do that, and it will only cause you unnecessary work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for the following:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Children { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(Model m)
    {
        Name = m.Name;
        Age = m.Age;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(m.Children.Select(md=>new ViewModel(md)));
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    public Model GetModel()
    {
        return new Model()
        {
            Age = Age,
            Name = Name,
            Children = Children.Select(vm=>vm.GetModel()).ToList(),
        };
    }
}
```

You will note that a lot of that is boilerplate code. But if you do it this way, your model/viewmodel are completely separated, which will save you SO many problems down the line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you. My main concern was to keep everything separate and not let Model class get anywhere near the view.

Comment: Just remember to keep everything in sync if you plan on letting it be changeable.  If you add / remove items from the observable, remember to do the same to the underlying model.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I was just about to ask about the same next. This doesn't do that, I realized. How exactly do I update the Model on changes to the VM?

Comment: With this, you wouldn't update the model - you'd just get a new one from the VM. You definitely need to do this at some point - when you do that is up to you - it depends on how you are using this.

Comment: You just have to add code to the vm. For example, in the setter for the vm name property, update model.name too. For the observable list, you can subscribe to its event, and change the model's list accordingly

Comment: Sorry for bombarding questions. But where exactly do I get to initialise the List from the Model class(`Children`)? In the VM constructor? at the moment, when I try to select from it, it is throwing an `ArgumentNullException` for obvious reasons.

Comment: And also what if I make changes to the List within the model after the initialization of the Collection in the constructor. How does it reflect the changes to the Collection?

Comment: @AkshathaPatil you are basically asking how to observe your model changes, but you designed your model in a way where it is not easily observable. I think that's going out of scope for the current question.

Comment: @grek40 Yeah, I kinda realised that too. Found out that this can be achieved by implementing `CollectionChanged` event and updating the Model when it fires.

Comment: Note also that the `GetModel()` method returns a different Model than the one from which the ViewModel was created. If you want to use the return value for Model comparison, you should either keep a reference to the source Model, or override `Model.Equals()`.